# Install TeX live and package offline and without root access

Tags: packages, installing

I use a old red hat distribution offline (no internet connexion) and I don't have root privilege, only some repository that I can work with.

I would like to install a newer TeX live version and some extra package. How should I proceed ? Is there any way to re-compile the source like `./configure make make install` ?

EDIT: My aim is to install some extra packages in this configuration

Comment: Why would you compile it manually? Much easier to rsync the entire tlnet repository from a mirror that supports rsync, to a PC with internet access. This repository data can then be copied to the RH box, and you can install from there. You do not need root access to install, just need the installation folder to be readable by you and that you afterwards know how to add the TL PATH to your normal PATH.

Comment: Why would you want to add a newer LaTeX to an old system that probably need to be replaced anyway?

Comment: @daleif what do you mean by "rsync the entire tlnet repository from a mirror that supports rsync" and where can I find such a mirror ? I'm ok with no recompile it manually and even keep my old version but I would like to add some extra packages and I don't know how to proceed in this situation

Comment: If I am not root you can guess that I am completely not able to replace the system.

Comment: @Welgriv You could download an .iso image https://www.tug.org/texlive/acquire-iso.html and install texlive from there. It should contain the full version, so no need to install extra packages.

Comment: But why are you forced to use this old system? It seems to me to be more of a management problem.

Comment: @daleif I don't **want** to use it I **have** to. It Is mandatory. I don't have any other choices. Anyway I am installing the .iso I'll come back if everything is ok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer partially provide by samcarter :

1. [Download last .iso](https://www.tug.org/texlive/acquire-iso.html) first link of the page.
2. Mount or extract the iso file in the dir `DIR`.
3. Go in `DIR/texlive20xx/`.
4. Run the script `install-tl` and follow the instructions. Install path and other stuff can be configure here. If your machine is offline untick "after install, use tlnet on CTAN for package updates" for obvious reasons.
5. You can remove any downloaded and extracted file.

## If final install or first run say that you need and do not have glibc-2.14 :

### Methode 1:

Restart from step 3 and

1. Follow [this](http://tug.org/texlive/custom-bin.html) link and download the "binaries for x86_64-linux-glibc2.12" in the seconde item.
2. Extract the .tar in `/tmp/foobin`.
3. Run `install-tl --custom-bin=/tmp/foobin`.
4. Add `DIR/bin/custom` to your PATH. The “/custom” there is literal.
5. You can remove any downloaded and extracted file.

### Methode 2:

I haven't tested this on :

Download the 2017 iso ftp://tug.org/historic/systems/texlive/2017/install-tl-unx.tar.gz and follow steps as normal. Solution suggested [here](https://tug.org/pipermail/tex-live/2018-April/041432.html).

Comment: And remember: using the ISO dies not include all the fixes that has come since the iso was released back in May. Imo rsyncing a copy of the current installation tree is better

Comment: I get what you mean but you still not provide any explanation how to "rsyncing a copy of the current installation tree" as I asked before.

Comment: The rsync method for getting a newer repository are described here https://www.tug.org/texlive/acquire-mirror.html you would need to use say that to build a portable set on a web aware machine then port  it on usb stick as repository for the dumb machine

Comment: Exactly as @KJO mentions. I rsync the tlnet folder to local disk on my Linux box. And transfer that folder to a USB, it even works if the USB is fat32 (you may get a few warnings about some symlinks noget working on fat32, but this is irrelevant. On the target, if there is space for it, copy the tlnet folder from the USB to local disk, and install using the install-tl script in the tlnet folder you just copied (important), this will pick up the local tlnet version and install from there. Just remember to make a folder you own, and instruct the installer to put the files there.

Comment: just ran rsync over a couple of hours ! to get 14,064 Files, in 447 Folders including those released in 2019 :-) and it came to **received 3830658215 bytes** (3.8 GB) on first run

Comment: "Mount or extract the iso file in the dir `DIR`" -- What is the command?

Comment: @hola You can use `7z` or `isoinfo` depending on your system, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17817673/7zip-iso-extraction

Comment: I was not able to use the USB stick method because my organization forbid USB stick connections for security reasons, and moreover the machine is a distant server that I cannot physically access

Comment: @Welgriv I finally used [`cmake`](https://askubuntu.com/a/1119307)